# GCP: Configurations on app service's versions

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, deployment, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I have been searching around gcloud documentations and around the web but could not find the way to set configurations for gcloud app services' version.

It has been done in my other project but I have forgotten how to update it again. What I wanted to do was to set maximum versions limit on single service - for example:

[image: gcloud app services page]

So that it only keeps up to 10 (for example) in the versions list, and also set to ignore certain version (for example, do not delete version "maintenance")

[image: gcloud app versions page]
[image: gcloud app versions page]

this is my `app.yaml`

```
env: flex
runtime: nodejs
service: application-one
resources:
  memory_gb: 4.0
  disk_size_gb: 10
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
env_variables:
  NODE_ENV: 'prod'
  APIHOST: 'http://10.146.0.1:32100'
```

On [GCP documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/an-overview-of-app-engine), it did mention about the maximum number of services and versions that we can deploy depends on your app's pricing, but I couldn't find out how to set max versions per app again.

[image: GCP documentation]

Does anyone have the documentation or any idea what the command is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m from the Google Cloud Platform support. At the moment, it’s not possible to set the maximum versions per App. This limit can be changed only internally after a request from the owner of the project if you have a support package.

That limit though isn’t for a specific service but for the app in general and again it can’t be set for specific services.

The functionality to prevent a version from getting deleted also doesn’t exist at the moment.

However, the above ideas could improve the App Engine product. The best course of action here would be to open a feature request for the product by following the instructions [here](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).

Also, if you file the requests, please file separate ones (one for the limit per service and another one for ignoring a specific version)

Hopefully, enough people will star the feature requests so that the relevant team can look into it.

Comment: Thanks @siamsot for the clarification here! Yeah, I've realized that it is actually not an existing Google Cloud Platform feature but a script that does the work for me. I think if this feature exists on GCP it will help a lot of people. I'll file these ideas!